# Upload a local image from assets to firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi i'm trying to upload a image from my folder assets to firebase storage but idk how can i upload

some code:

```
File  fil = File("assets/usuariDef.png");

Future<void> resUser() async {
  try {
    final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(

      email: _gmailController.text,
      password: _contrasenaController.text,
    );

    final uid = userCredential.user!.uid;

    String newDirectory = uid;

   await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('imagenes/$uid/').putFile(fil);

    addUser(_usuarioController.text, _gmailController.text, _contrasenaController.text,uid);

  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors
    print('Error creating user: $e');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly import dependency in Pubspec.yaml -> **firebase_storage: ^11.0.10**

After Select Image from Gallery or Assets use below method

```
void uploadImage(String value) async {
if (await Utils.hasNetwork()) {
  Utils.showLoader();
  File image = File(value);
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference ref =
      storage.ref().child("${SharedPreferenceHelper().getUserId()}");
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
  uploadTask.then((res) {
    if (res.state == TaskState.success) {
      res.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) {
       print(url);
      }).catchError((onError) {
        print("Got Error $onError");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

}